# How to bind CGPDFDocumentRef?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I assume CGPDFDocumentRef should be bind to CGPDFDocument

I'm trying the following

```
    //- (id)initWithPDFDocument:(CGPDFDocumentRef)_document filepath:(NSString *)fullFilePath;
    [Export("initWithPDFDocument:filepath:")]
IntPtr Constructor (CGPDFDocument document, string path);
```

I'm also including:

```
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
```

When I try to compile my binding project, I'm getting following error:

```
: error BI1002: btouch: Unknown kind MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGPDFDocument document in method 'pdftest.ReaderDocument.Constructor'
```

EDIT:

After input from poupou, I have the following:

```
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    partial interface ReaderDocument {

    [Export("initWithPDFDocument:filepath:")] 
    [Internal] IntPtr Constructor (IntPtr document, string path);
```

AND in extras.cs:

```
    public partial class ReaderDocument {
        public ReaderDocument (CGPDFDocument doc, string path) : this (doc.Handle, path) { }
    }
```

I can Build my bindingproject in MonoDevelop, but I'm getting following error in btouch.
I'm using the command "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch MyBindingLib.cs -s:extras.cs"

```
MyBindingLib.cs(12,19): error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration 
of type `mybindingtest.ReaderDocument'. Another partial declaration of this type 
exists
extras.cs(6,30): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
extras.cs(6,30): error CS0261: Partial declarations of `mybindingtest.ReaderDocument' 
must be all classes, all structs or all interfaces
```

Comment: Can you post your `btouch` command and args you are using?

Comment: Also why not using XamarinStudio's iOS Binding Project? it would simplify your binding experience a lot :)

Comment: Btw, the answer below is correct, I have implemented it myself several times, does not matter if it is a constructor, you can check this project, contains tons of examples were btouch cannot handle automagically https://github.com/PSPDFKit/XamarinBindings

Comment: Thanks. I was using the iOS Binding Project, but I wasn't aware that this automatically creates the DLL file in a specific subfolder :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btouch` does not know every types that exists, only the basic ones and the one you define. In this case you can bind this in two steps.

First bind `CGPDFDocumentRef` as an `IntPtr` and decorate it as `[Internal]`.

```
[Export("initWithPDFDocument:filepath:")]
[Internal]
IntPtr Constructor (IntPtr document, string path);
```

Next add a custom constructor in your `Extra.cs` file.

```
partial public class YourType {
   public YourType (CGPDFDocument doc, string path) : this (doc.Handle, path) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you poupou. With the changes, I can not build my DLL file (with btouch). I have edited my starting post with the changes. I saw in extras.cs file from the GoogleMaps binding that they are also mentioning a partial class for an interface. So not sure why it's not working at my side (maybe because I'm defining a constructor)

Answer (score 0):

There's an example that uses a CGPDFDocument in the Core Graphics seminar:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNxVMYKaZP0

The relevant code is here:

https://github.com/xamarin/Seminars/blob/master/2012-01-26-CoreGraphics/XaminarPDFDemo/XaminarPDFDemo/PDFView.cs

Comment: This question is about binding a custom obj-c class to a C# class.